# Why can not I be cast?

Tags: c#, list, casting, ienumerable

> Unable to cast object type
>   "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NorthwindMVC3.Models.Product]" to
>   the type
>   of"System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1[NorthwindMVC3.Models.Product]".\

```
public IEnumerator<Product> GetEnumerator()
{     
      IEnumerable<Product> myEnumerable = Products.ToList();
      return (IEnumerator<Product>) myEnumerable;
}

public class ProductsList : IEnumerable<Product>
    {
        public ProductsList()
        {
            Products  =new List<Product>();
        }
        public List<Product> Products { get; private set; }
```

Why can not I?

Comment: There's a difference between a List (which is enumerable) and an enumerator (which enumerates an enumerable collection).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `myEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`

Even better: `return Products.GetEnumerator();`